# C++ Error 2084: "already has body"

Tags: c++

I am not quite sure why i am getting this error. Maybe i am just blind or the error may be from another source.
this is the error i get (i'm sry its in german)
Fehler  1   error C2084: Funktion 'void Enemy::loseHp(int)' hat bereits einen Funktionsrumpf    h:\oop\oop\enemy.cpp    73

Here is my header file:

```
   #ifndef ENEMY_H
    #define ENEMY_H
    class Enemy
    {
    private:

        int atk;                        // Angriffsattribut
        int def;                        // Verteidigungsattribut
        int hp;                         // Lebensattribut

    public:
        Enemy(void);                    // Konstruktor
        Enemy(int, int, int);// Konstruktor mit eigenen Werten
        ~Enemy(void);                   // Destruktor

        // get/set Methoden

        int getAtk();                   // Liefert Angriffwert zurück
        void setAtk(int);           // Legt einen Angriffswert fest

        int getDef();                   // Liefert Verteidigungswert zurück
        void setDef(int);           // Legt einen Verteidigungswert fest

        int getHp();                    // Liefert Lebenswert zurück
        void setHp(int);            // Legt einen Lebenswert fest

        //------------------------------------------------------
        void init(int, int, int);
        void Attack(Enemy*);        // Methode, welche einen Angriff simuliert
        void loseHp(int);           // Methode, welche das Verlieren von Leben simuliert
    };

    #endif
```

Here's the .cpp file

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <iostream>


Enemy::Enemy(void) : atk(0), def(0), hp(0)
{
    std::cout << typeid(this).name() << " wurde instanziert.\n";
}
Enemy::Enemy(int atk, int def, int hp)
{
    this->atk = atk;
    this->def = def;
    this->hp = hp;
    std::cout << typeid(this).name() << " wurde instanziert.\n";

}

Enemy::~Enemy(void)
{

}

#pragma region Getter&Setter
int Enemy::getAtk()
{
    return this->atk;
}

void Enemy::setAtk(int value)
{
    this->atk = value;
}

void Enemy::loseHp(int value)
{
    this->setHp(this->getHp() - value);
}

int Enemy::getDef()
{
    return this->def;
}
void Enemy::setDef(int value)
{
    this->def = value;
}

int Enemy::getHp()
{
    return this->hp;
}

void Enemy::setHp(int value)
{
    this->hp = value;
}
#pragma endregion

void Enemy::loseHp(int value)
{
    int currHp;
    currHp = this->getHp();
    currHp -= value;
    this->setHp(value);
    std::cout << typeid(this).name() << " hat " << value << "Leben verloren!\n";
}
void Enemy::Attack(Enemy* enemy)
{
    int tmpAtk = this->getAtk();
    int enemyDefense = enemy->getDef();
    int totalAtk = tmpAtk - enemyDefense;
    if(totalAtk > 0) {
        std::cout << typeid(this).name() << " hat " << typeid(enemy).name() << " angegriffen und " << totalAtk << " Schaden hinzugefügt!\n";
        enemy->loseHp(totalAtk);
    }
    else if (totalAtk <= 0){return;}
}



void Enemy::init(int atk, int def, int hp)
{
    this->setAtk(atk);
    this->setDef(def);
    this->setHp(hp);
}
```

And finally my main function

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "Enemy.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Enemy Drache;
    Enemy Greif; 
    Drache.init(100,25,200);
    Greif.init(250,10,100);

    Greif.Attack(&Drache);



    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should rewrite this question as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Read the error message again, then look at the source file where the message tells you the error is. There is probably more messages output by the compiler, telling you the location of the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In your .cpp file, `Enemy::loseHp(int)` is defined in two different ways:

> ```
> void Enemy::loseHp(int value)
> {
>     this->setHp(this->getHp() - value);
> }
>
> ...
>
> void Enemy::loseHp(int value)
> {
>     int currHp;
>     currHp = this->getHp();
>     currHp -= value;
>     this->setHp(value);
>     std::cout << typeid(this).name() << " hat " << value << "Leben verloren!\n";
> }
> ```

Provide just one definition for it.

Comment: Well so i was just blind ._.
Anyways thank you very much, working the whole day doesn't seem to be healthy :D

Comment: @Loqicx: You're welcome :) Sometimes a couple of fresh eyes looking at your code can be helpful :)